# Remove Square Brackets and replace with Curly Brackets

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to replace all the square brackets with the curly brackets.

Example:

```
String string = "{\"test\":{\"id\":["4,5,6"}]},{\"Tech\":["Java,C++"]}}";
```

I want to remove square brackets([,]) and replace them with curly brackets({,}).

Like:

```
"{\"test\":{\"id\":{"4,5,6"}}},{\"Tech\":{"Java,C++"}}}";
```

I have tried:

```
string = string.replace("\\[", "\\{").replace("\\]", "\\}");
```

But didnt worked.Need some suggestions here.

Comment: Just an idea: for such a simple replacement, you could go with [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: @domdom i have tried that. But it didnt worked :(

Comment: Wait, my comment was rubbish anyway. I just scanned over your question and thought you were using regex. Ignore me.

Comment: Why you use the "\\" before [ , ]. No need that. string = string.replaceAll("[", "{").replaceAll("]", "}");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `\\[` and `\\{` for that you don't get the correct result, instead you can use :

```
System.out.println(string.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}"));
```

**Note**

Your are using an invalid String you have to use `\` before `"\""` like this :

```
String string = "{\"test\":{\"id\":[\"4,5,6\"}]},{\"Tech\":[\"Java,C++\"]}}";
```

Comment: I think you could remove the `System.out.println()` for a more straightforward answer. After all, we don't know what is supposed to happen to the String next.

Answer (score 0):

you can either do this:

```
str.replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}');
```

or you can do this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\[", "{").replaceAll("\\]", "}");
```

Replace uses Characters, thus the ' ' whereas replaceAll uses Regex. This is why you should escape your bracket there.